# Singleton with Enum called by threads

Tags: java, singleton

Hi can any one help me understand the output of the below snippet?

Enum -

```
public enum SingletonEnum {
  INSTANCE;
  int num;

  public void demo(){
    System.out.println(num);
  }
}
```

Main Class -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            SingletonEnum samp = SingletonEnum.INSTANCE;
            samp.num= 5;
            samp.demo();
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            SingletonEnum temp = SingletonEnum.INSTANCE;
            temp.num= 8;
            temp.demo();
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();     
}
```

The o/p is 8 and 8 .However if i add a private constructor in the enum the o/p is 5 and 8. What is the logic behind the o/p being 8 and 8.

Comment: That's probably a racing condition, i.e. `t2` sets the value 8 before `t1` calls `demo()`. Note that `samp` and `temp` refer to the _exact same_ instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is not synchronized. This is simply unspecified behavior, you can observe anything in such case.

Comment: Right, just started working with enums on singleton and completely forgot that the methods and everything declared inside an enum are not thread safe. Thank you so much .